# what is the error? (SELECT [Data] FROM Split(@ProductName,','))

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

The stored procedure that used work with multiple parameters but it stops working.

I am trying to fix the stored procedure that used to work but suddenly create an error 'Invalid object name 'Split''.  This is the procedure that someone else wrote so I am not exactly sure what 'Split' is.   Is this some sort of command or what?

This is the stored Procedure that used to work but not anymore.

```
DECLARE @ProductName NVARCHAR(MAX) = '9x95dk36-2727-9401-8948-161740000000,150t3vh6-1230-4449-8846-173120000000'


SELECT
    m.[member_id]
    , m.external_member_id
    , m.last_name
    , m.first_name
    , m.middle_name
    , e.effective_date
    ,[termination_date]
    , REPLACE(bhp.name_full_path,'CW > Medicaid > WI > SSI > ','') AS BHP
    , pr.product_name
    ,pr.product_ID
INTO #ActiveSSIMembers
FROM 
    [Eligibility] as e
    INNER JOIN Product as pr on e.product_id = pr.product_id
    INNER JOIN Member as m on e.member_id = m.member_id
    INNER JOIN BhpNode as bhp on m.bhp_node_id = bhp.bhp_node_id
WHERE 

    pr.product_ID IN (SELECT [Data] FROM Split(@ProductName,','))
```

We need to use multiple parameters for the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have posted, it seems `Split` is a [Table-Valued User-Defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-use-table-valued-user-defined-functions) function that takes `NVarchar` parameter(seperated by ',') and returns rows of split values under the column name `Data`.

You are missing that user-defined function in your database where this query is being executed. Either this has been removed or you running the query in a different database.

Try navigating to Table-Valued Functions as below and make sure you have a function called **Split** in there(instead of 'TestFunction' in that image). If not, you can create your our function to split the values and add it to your database.

You can take help from [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21078/t-sql-table-valued-function-to-split-a-column-on-commas) thread to create one

[image]

Comment: Thank you!   Yes, the function was deleted somehow.    I put it back and it works!